# Birthday Date range validation issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to validate my date of birth field validation

I need the age range has to be 18-45

I tried the following rule, but it's not working properly.

```
'date_of_birth_tcp2'=>'required|date|before:18 years|after:45 years'
```

Comment: for 18 year `'date_of_birth_tcp2' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:'.\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(18)->format('Y-m-d'),`

Comment: no, my min-age has to be 18 and max-age has to be 45, when I tried to apply your rule it allows me to submit 1900-10-21, which i should display an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using custom validation or as mentioned in comment.

```
'date_of_birth_tcp2'=>['required','date',  function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        
        $age=Carbon::parse($value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
        //$age=Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
        if($age<18||$age>45){
            $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
        }
       
    },]
```

Comment: I tried, 2010-10-12, still says The date_of_birth_tcp2 is invalid. my date format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: yes  correct because its not completing 18 years if you consider difference between today to that mentioned year date

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validation rule within your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot() {
    Validator::extend('valid_date_range', function ($attribute, $value, $parameter, $validator) {
        $dob = Carbon::parse($value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;

        if($dob < 18 || $dob > 45) {
            return $fail('The given '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
        }
    });
}
```

To use this rule:

```
$this->validate([
    'date_of_birth_tcp2' => 'valid_date_range:date_of_birth,3',
]);
```